# Did jQuery change $(event.target)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm using jQuery 1.11.3.

The behavior of `$(event.target)` seems to have changed from previous versions?

HTML/pseudocode...

```
<div class="action_button" data-item-id=" #{ object.id } ">Do something</div>
```

JavaScript...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.action_button').click(function(event) {
    var object_id = $(event.target).attr('data-item-id');
    doSomething(object_id);
  });
});
```

`$(event.target)` no longer returns a jQuery object.

In Chrome's debugger this is what I'm seeing...

[image]

`$(this)` works, though.

I can get the functionality I want with something like...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.action_button').click(function(event) {
    var object_id = $(this).attr('data-item-id');
    doSomething(object_id);
  });
});
```

The [jQuery API docs](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) seem to be saying `$(event.target)` still does the same thing I've always been used to.

Has there been a major change or conceptual shift I should be aware of?

Comment: It looks like you're looking at `event_target` in the debugger instead of `event.target`

Comment: Regardless of the issue with `event.target`, it's better to use `this` within the handler anyway.

Comment: It hasn't changed. Otherwise it would break a lot of existing code if people upgraded to it. Proof that it still works: http://jsfiddle.net/1mr3bp33 Are you able to create a demo of your problem? Note that even if `event.target` is undefined `$(event.target)` still returns a jQuery object, but it will contain no elements.

Comment: @winhowes Nope. I'm definitely watching `$(event.target)`. Look a little closer.

Comment: Why would you even bother assigning $(event.target) to a variable in the first place? Could you provide a more complete set of code as @nnnnnn has asked for? This seems like only 1/2 a puzzle to solve.